# How to push entire json object into another object in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am struggling to push one object into another. I have a multidimensional JSON object like

```
{
   "item1":{
      "key":"Value",
      "key":"Value"
   },
   "item2":{
      "key":"Value",
      "key":"Value"
   },
   "item3":{
      "key":"Value",
      "key":"Value",
      "subItem3":{
         "key":"Value",
         "key":"Value"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to push item3 in item2 like

```
{
   "item1":{
      "key":"Value",
      "key":"Value"
   },
   "item2":{
      "key":"Value",
      "key":"Value",
      "item3":{
         "key":"Value",
         "key":"Value",
         "subItem3":{
            "key":"Value",
            "key":"Value"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How to achieve that any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is vague at the moment. And the given input object is wrong. An object cannot have duplicate properties. Adjusting for these errors, you could probably use `Object.entries()` to get an iterable array of the object and use `Array#reduce` on it to transform it to the required form

Try the following

```js
const input = {
  "item1": {
    "key1": "Value1",
    "key2": "Value2"
  },
  "item2": {
    "key1": "Value1",
    "key2": "Value2"
  },
  "item3": {
    "key1": "Value1",
    "key2": "Value2",
    "subItem3": {
      "key1": "Value1",
      "key2": "Value2"
    }
  }
};

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (key === 'item3')
    acc['item2'] = { ...acc['item2'], [key]: value };
  else 
    acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it's in a variable myObject.

```
myObject.item2.item3 = myObject.item3;
delete myObject.item3;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```js
let items = {
       "item1":{
          "key":"Value",
          "key":"Value"
       },
       "item2":{
          "key":"Value",
          "key":"Value"
       },
       "item3":{
          "key":"Value",
          "key":"Value",
          "subItem3":{
             "key":"Value",
             "key":"Value"
          }
       }
    }

    items.item2.item3 = items.item3
    delete items.item3

    console.log(items)
```

Comment: That's wrong because you're not preserving the properties that were already in item2. See my answer. We had the same idea around the same time.